# How to extract out all multiple ID's of the same person in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

Say that I am given a data-model with different entities connected to each other with one-many or many-one relationships. I am suppose to find the songs that were done by the artist AKON. How can we use the sequel query to find that. He has multiple ID's in the the entity which then is used to find the Song he did. How can we use the SQL to find those out.

Say we are given the ID's (1,10002,2908) but we do not know those, all we do know is the name 'AKON' which helps us to find the different ID's and all the songs connected with those ID's

Comment: can you show the database structure  for that  is there any author colum or you are adding author in the  content part

Comment: @VikasGautam Idk how to make a datamodel on the Stackoverflow.

But its one entity in which the ID is stored of Song and that links to ID of the artist in our case Akon who has multiple ID's. So how can i get out all the three ID's and extract all the songs that were done by him?!

Comment: I thing @florian have right answer already for this

Comment: @VikasGautam : His solution works but only gives me the first output and not the rest of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm sounds like a simple Join query.

```
SELECT a.songid FROM db.songs a 
INNER JOIN db.artists b on b.artistid=a.artistid
WHERE b.artistname='AKON'
```

Is that what you´re looking for?

Comment: Its only giving me one output of the first ID song and not the others.

Comment: Btw the Songs is connected to the production and the production is then connected to the Artists. Could that be the problem?

Comment: You have to show us how your db model looks like. We can´t know how the tables are connected. 
When you say only one record: How do you query via a script language? Or do you do he query directly on mysql.

Comment: If you use a script language you have to use something like a loop to get all the data. 

If you want to get the data all in one row you can use GROUP_CONCAT(songid) as allsongids

Comment: Query is done on mysql. 


Film -----> Production ------> Artists. With one to many relation and many to one respectively. With the production in the middle.

Comment: Just use production with an extra join:

SELECT a.filmid FROM db.film a  
INNER JOIN db.production b on b.filmid=a.filmid  
INNER JOIN db.artists c on b.productionid=c.productionid 
WHERE c.artistname='AKON'

Comment: Thanks so much that works man, but the only bug now is that everything is duplicated. its giving the right output but has duplicates in them

Comment: or just add:  
GROUP BY a.filmid